# Can I have multiple people digitally sign an Excel spreadsheet on a limited number of computers.

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have created a simple spread sheet that requires my employees to digitally sign.  I have about 30 employees and 10 computers. It seems that if one employee creates a digital signature, they are the only one that can sign on that computer.  What am I missing?

Comment: Are they logging out and logging into their account?